# How to add sliding page transition in a Single Page App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, sammy.js

I am using Sammy.JS for my routes and I can hide and show my pages with its callback, but the transition isn't good. What I wanted is to show the pages from right to left or when going back, it would be left to right.

```
var app = Sammy('body', function() {

    this.get('#/start', function() {
        $('.app_page').hide();
        $('#start').show();
    });

    this.get('#/end', function() {
        $('.app_page').hide();
        $('#end').show();
    });

});
```

Is there any frameworks or Plugins for this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are looking for something like the android transition between pages, in that case you must know that web is not totally ready for that and although it's possible, but you must consider many problems that happen when animation pages, such as the positioning(you must set the positioning as fixed and that might cause a lot of problem) or the performance of the animation for long and heavy pages.
there is not a mature javascript library that I've encountered and everybody just use their own code cause for different webpages, different css stylings are needed.
the best way to have a nice animation is to keep is simple and light, like a fading effect with a little bit of transform and scaling.
and if you really want to do the animation, it's better that you do it yourself, definitely use css animation(not jquery) and remove the animation after it's done(for performance).
and write a javascript function to check if animation is supported if not do it the old fashion way.
if you need more information let me know.
I did try the page transition in my own javascript framework and it works fine but only after I failed the first 100 time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to you to use `jquery animation` to achieve your goal.

- First, you can study css `transition`(for the page right to left effect.)
- Second, you can use jquery animation with `.show()`, [Example](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

You can combine these tricks to satisfied what you want.